# C# - scheduling a task to run every X minutes

Tags: c#, scheduling, scheduled-tasks

I am using a TaskFactory to manage my program's tasks. I would like to add a task to the queue that will start running after X minutes. Can it be done using .Net's standard tools or do I need to use a custom library for that.

Thanks

Comment: Seriously? You read the documentation and didn't come across one of the 3 or 4 different `Timer` classes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you objective is to run something after a while you could use the `Timer`

Start the `Timer`, when the timer has elapsed, stop the `Timer`.

Comment: Thanks, I guess I will use the Timer to add a task on the TaskFactory.

Answer (score 2):

Yes this can be quite easily achieved. Look into some articles of basic multi-threading to ensure your UI is still responsive when scheduling/running these tasks. As has already been mentioned - the Timer control will do the trick.

The Programmers Heaven EBook on C#'s multi-threading section has enough in it to do what you want with regards to the multi-threading.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a single-shot `Timer` that creates your `Task` when it fires. This means you won't be blocking a thread while you are waiting.

If you are writing a scheduler, you might want to look at [Quartz.NET](http://quartznet.sourceforge.net/)